# data cant be inserted to the sqlit database tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert data in my sqlit database  but I got android SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed exception. I saw there are tons of question in this topic, I've read and tried  a bunch of them,  but the exception still , i wonder if this exception caused by the  auto increment food_id value , since the insert statement return -1 ,  and i wonder that why this exception occur since the first insert id done correctly but all the later inserting are failed ,  why  this  error occur ,and how i can solve it? please help me..

**the create statements in  the DBAdapter class**

```
private static final String Meal_TABLE_CREATE= "create table IF NOT EXISTS Meal (Date  text not null , "+
        "Time   text not null,MealType  text not null,"+ " primary key(Date,Time ,MealType) );" ;

private static final String FOOD_TABLE_CREATE= "create table IF NOT EXISTS Food (_id  INTEGER  primary key  AUTOINCREMENT  , "+
        "Food_Name   text not null,Calories  integer  not null,"+ "VB12   integer  not null,Cholesterol  integer  not null,"+ 
        "Protein   integer  not null,Iron integer  not null,Sodium integer  not null,Fat_Mono integer  not null,Fat_Sat integer  not null,carbohydrate integer  not null);" ;

private static final String MealFOOD_TABLE_CREATE= "create table IF NOT EXISTS MealFood (Date  text  not null , "+
        "Time   text not null,MealType  text not null,"+"Food_ID  integer   not null ,  primary key(Date,Time ,MealType,Food_ID) );" ;
```

**inserting methods**

```
// insert meal  to the meal table 
public long SaveMeal(String date , String time , String mealType)
{
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(KEY_MDATE,date);
    content.put(KEY_MTIME,time);
    content.put(KEY_MEALTYPE,mealType);
    return db.insert(MEAL_TABLE_NAME, null, content);

}

// insert Food  to the Food table 
public long SaveFood(String name,int calories,int Vit_B12,int cholesterol,int protein ,int iron ,int sodium,int Fat_Mono,int Fat_Sat,int carbohydrate)
{
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();

    content.put(KEY_FOODNAME,name);
    content.put(KEY_CALORIES,calories);
    content.put(KEY_VB12,Vit_B12);
    content.put(KEY_CHOLESTEROL,cholesterol);
    content.put(KEY_PROTEIN,protein);
    content.put(KEY_IRON,iron);
    content.put(KEY_SODIUM,sodium);
    content.put(KEY_FAT_MONO,Fat_Mono);
    content.put(KEY_FAT_Sat,Fat_Sat);
    content.put(KEY_CARBOHYDRATE,carbohydrate);


    return db.insert(FOOD_TABLE_NAME, null, content);

}

// get food id by its name   

public int getFoodIDByName(String name) throws SQLException
{   int id;
Cursor cursor = null;

try{

    cursor=db.query(true,FOOD_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{KEY_FOODID},  KEY_FOODNAME+ " = '" + name + "'", null, null, null, null,null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    id=0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
        id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FOODID));

}
finally{
    cursor.close();
    cursor.deactivate(); 
}
return id;

}


// insert mealFood   to mealFood table 
public long SaveMealFood(String date , String time , String mealType, int Food_id)
{
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(KEY_MFDATE,date);
    content.put(KEY_MFTIME,time);
    content.put(KEY_MFMEALTYPE,mealType);
    content.put(KEY_MFFOODID,Food_id);
    return db.insert(MEALFOOD_TABLE_NAME, null, content);

}
```

**java code**

```
 DBAdapter dbAdapter=new DBAdapter(SaveMeal.this);
      dbAdapter.open();
      Food n;
     String m;
     int FoodIDByName;
     for(int i = 0; i <MealActivity.array.size(); i++){
        m=MealActivity.array.get(i).toString();
        Log.e("tag", m);//selected food name
       for (int j = 0; j < MealActivity.tempList.size(); j++){
              n=MealActivity.tempList.get(j);

              if(n.getFOOD_NAME().equals(m)){
         //save food 
 long food_id = dbAdapter.SaveFood(n.getFOOD_NAME(),n.getCALORIES(),n.getFOOD_VITAMIN_B12(),n.getCHOLESTEROL(),n.getFOOD_PROTEIN(),n.getFOOD_IRON(),n.getFOOD_SODIUM(),
 n.getFOOD_MONO_UNSATURATED_FAT(),n.getFOOD_SATURATED_FAT(),n.getFOOD_TOTAL_CARBOHYDRATE()); 
  Log.e("tag", food_id+" food inserting done");

  //save meal
 long meal_id=  dbAdapter.SaveMeal( meal_date,meal_time,Meal.MEAL_TYPE);
Log.e("tag",meal_id+" meal inserting done");

//save meal_food 
 FoodIDByName=dbAdapter.getFoodIDByName(n.FOOD_NAME);
 Log.e("tag",FoodIDByName+" food_id");
    long      meal_food_id=dbAdapter.SaveMealFood(meal_date,meal_time,Meal.MEAL_TYPE,FoodIDByName);
Log.e("tag",meal_food_id+" meal_food  inserting done");
 dbAdapter.close();
```

this result of this line Log.e("tag", food_id+" food inserting done"); in my log is -1

**mylog**

```
   Database(657):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native       Method)
   Database(657):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute                 (SQLiteStatement.java:55)
   Database(657):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)         
   -1 food inserting done
   18 meal inserting done 
   0 food_id
    13 meal_food inserting done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove all (Not NULL) constraints, and save the empty food.
If it is saved properly, try to add the constraint (NOT NULL) one by one.

I think one of the values is passed as NULL.

Comment: yes the primary key in the food table , the first time i tried to insert data into the food table its created and has auto value but in the next times its value always zero and didnt inserted  successfully, why is that?  is the way i used to insert the auto increment primary key not correct?

Comment: Try to change the primary key id from _id to something else, may be it is used by android itself.... maybe

Answer (score 0):

That error.means you are.violating a constraint (obviously).  Most likely leave a "not null" column null.

You could also have violated your primary key by trying to save the same combination more than once.

Comment: but i inserted all values in the tables , and the food table i inserted all values except  food_id(_id) since its auto increment

Comment: Updated my answer with another possible constraint violation.